# How to use this data from Vuex inside the component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

What is the best way to use this data from the Vuex store's  Action in the needed component?

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  namespaced: true,

  state: {
    items: []
  },
  actions: {
    fetchCategories ({state, commit}) {
      return axios.get('/api/v1/categories')
        .then(res => {
          const categories = res.data
          commit('setItems', {resource: 'categories', items: categories}, {root: true})
          return state.items
        })
    }
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
  export default {
    components: {
      ThreadCreateModal,
      ThreadList
    },
    data () {
      return {
       ...
      }
    },
    computed: {
   ...
    },
    created () {
     ...
    },

    methods: {
    ...

  }
</script>
```

Where and how should I use that action for binding the data in this component?

Answer (score 1):

Use `mapState` by import it from vuex  and call it in computed:

```
computed: {
  ...mapState(['items']), // if you dont use namespace
  ...mapState("your_module_name", ['items'] ) // if you use namespace
},
```

then you can access it by `this.items`.
However, you can access it directly `this.$store.state.items`

Comment: So action inside created hook with spinner is not needed? If loading takes time.

Comment: That part is confusing. How can be it done with a spinner?  Shouldn't action be used?

Comment: you fill state by call action, for access state need mapState, u commited `setItems ` however dont have mutations `setItems `

Comment: setItems are inside store js as mutation

Comment: it's reusable so staid there.

Comment: I cant find action inside created in code you posted, How you want receive data from server by call actio? so you need to call it to receive/ manipulate data

Comment: Look action is in the question. I mean no matter the way but the option which you wrote inside the component isn't better to use spinner before data will be received inside the template? I mean that part how can be fixed or done?
Let's say there is a <spinner> component

Comment: I dont understand what you want to do, if i understood correctly, you want just use this data in spinner component then you dont need use store, We use store when we want share data between components

Comment: Nope look. Spinner is another component. I will import it in this categories component. And until data is fetching it will show a spinner. Once data is ready and the fetched spinner will be removed.

Comment: usual list fetching cycle

Comment: for spinner, you can use  another boolean state like `isLoading`, while you are receiving data `isLoading` is `true` and spinner shows, when received data, put `isLoading = false` and show items, this isnt related to your main question

Comment: So vuex is not needed right in that case? just data method should be used

Comment: if you dont share `items` with other components no, you can define `items` in data and `fetchCategories` in methods